# Menubar depending on route/login-status

Tags: ember.js

So in my ember-app I want have a main-navigation and a subnavigation. Depending on the route I want to either display no menu, the mainnav or mainnav + subnav.
So the way I have been thinking of handling it, is two outlets in the application.hbs

```
{{outlet header}}
{{outlet}}
```

and another outlet in the mainnav.hbs to handle the subnav dynamically.

And in each route I define the renderTemplate function. That works fine but is quite tedious, since I have to copy code whenever I create a new route
This is e.g. how the index route looks like:

```
this.render('index');
this.render('layouts/_mainnav', {
    outlet:'header'
});
```

And while that is not too much code that gets copied it still has to be done for every route and also seems like it could be optimized. So is there anyway that can be done without copying code or any complete different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are maintaining some state related to the user's session/route within your application you can use that within an `application` template to do the conditional rendering. The individual templates can be organized with `{{partial}}` helpers to still keep them separated.

For example a header partial would be provided by,

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='_header'>
  {{partial 'mainmenu'}}
  {{#if App.loggedIn}}
    {{partial 'submenu'}}
  {{/if}}
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='_mainmenu'>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" {{action 'login'}}>Login</button>
    <button class="btn" {{action 'logout'}}>Logout</button>
  </div>  
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='_submenu'>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Profile</button>
    <button class="btn">Settings</button>
  </div>  
</script>
```

Here the full [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/obibuj/2/edit) example.

This is a trade off that you may need to make based on the complexity of the interface design. `renderTemplate` offers greater flexibility, whereas `{{partials}}` in the application template reduces code duplication, at the cost of some logic in the templates.

Comment: Thank you Darshan. We decided to stick with multiple outlets and `renderTemplate` the way we have it, but good to know we where thinking in right directions